# Can RequiredFieldValidator have an effect on other elements on the page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html

I have a basic form on my page with the following textbox and validator. When the validator is visible, there is a background image that is displayed. I would also like to be able to change the border of the textbox. Is that possible? If not in the ascx file, would it be possible in Javascript?

```
<tr>
  <td class="FormLabel">First name*</td>
  <td class="FormInput">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstname" runat="server" Width="180" MaxLength="30" fieldname="FIRSTNAME" tablename="TblName"></asp:TextBox></td>
  <td class="FormValidation">
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valFirstname" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstname" CssClass="ValidatorError">&nbsp;</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you would use a [ValidatorCalloutExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx) of the ASP.NET-Ajax-Control-Toolkit, this would be simple by applying an appropriate `HighlightCssClass`.

Comment: Shall i add this as answer so that you can accept it to close this question or do you want to delete it?

Comment: Best to add it as an answer and close it, at least it is a reference to someone else - I couldn't find anything on google without knowing about the ValidatorCalloutExtender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use a [ValidatorCalloutExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx) of the ASP.NET-Ajax-Control-Toolkit, this would be simple by applying an appropriate `HighlightCssClass`.